# Temporary Disable Keyup event when text input is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in jquery but I've tried my best to do this, but unfortunately I missed something

How can I temporary disable keyup event when text input is blank and enable it again after I have typed something on it?

I cannot cannot catch backspace in keypress so I used keyup. Here is my code

```
$('#searchBox').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode != '18' && e.keyCode != '91' && e.keyCode != '17' && e.keyCode != '16' && e.keyCode != '20' && e.keyCode != '27' && e.keyCode != '113' && e.keyCode != '115' && e.keyCode != '118' && e.keyCode != '119' && e.keyCode != '120' && e.keyCode != '122' && e.keyCode != '123' && e.keyCode != '44' && e.keyCode != '19' && e.keyCode != '45' && e.keyCode != '46' && e.keyCode != '36' && e.keyCode != '33' && e.keyCode != '34' && e.keyCode != '35' && e.keyCode != '39' && e.keyCode != '37' && e.keyCode != '38' && e.keyCode != '9'){
    if(e.keyCode == '8' && $(this).val()==""){
        //what will i put here
    }else if(e.keyCode == '8' && $(this).val()!=""){
        refreshWookmark($(this).val());
    }else{
        refreshWookmark($(this).val());
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish? It seems like there are only a few keystrokes for which 'key-up' would NOT have left something in the textbox?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Eric! It's general SO practice to post code of what you have tried in your question so folks can help you.

Comment: I think you would need a keyup (or keydown, etc.) event to track whether you should re-enable the keyup event...

Comment: I deleted mine because I don't think I fully grasp what you are trying to do here.

Comment: How many handlers (bound to the keyup event) are you trying to prevent from executing?

Comment: My point below was that if you bind a keyup event handler, and then return from it, that won't override the browsers default behavior for the keyup event unless you prevent default. I said stop propagation by mistake.

Comment: I just like to catch the letters, numbers, special characters, backspace, space and enter. But if you think you can improve or something that it will work on different type of event I will be graceful.

Comment: @EricNilo keyup probably isn't the right event if that's the case

Comment: i tried to capture all the keyCode stuff in my answer. you really need to do it better than a giant `if` statement.

Comment: @crush then what will it be? In keypress I cannot catch the backspace so I rather used the keyup and prevent the other keyboard function to execute.

Comment: Wouldn't keydown prevent it from executing better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than disable it, just check that input exists and that the `keyCode` is what you consider valid:

```
$('#searchBox').on('keyup',function(e){
    var bad = ['18','91','17','16','20','27','113','115','118','119','120','122','123','44','19','45','46','36','33','34','35','39','37','38','9'],
        isBad = false;

    for(var i=bad.length;i--;){
        if(e.keyCode == bad[i]){
            isBad = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(this.value.length > 0 && !isBad){
        refreshWookmark(this.value);
    }
});
```

This will only run the function u want when input exists and the `keyCode` is correct, which I think is what you were going for.

Also, 99.9% of the time you can use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`. This saves the overhead of wrapping `this` into a jQuery object, then using the internal method to get the value (which is basically `this.value`).

Comment: thanks @EricNilo, thats what i get for just gunslinging the answer!

Answer (score 1):

To disable keyup function or others functions try this

```
  if()
    {
    obj.keyup(function () {
    //code
    });
    }else{
    obj.unbind("keyup")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `return` on blank input:

```
$("#idOfElement").keyup(function() {
    if (!this.value == '') {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: The keyup event would still happen, though...I thought he wanted to disable it.

Comment: It will happen but all the functionality will be gone, I feel this is easier than unbinding and rebinding.

Comment: He needs to stop propagation. Maybe I'm just not understanding what he is wanting.

Comment: Stop propagation stops the event from bubbling up, why would he want that?

Comment: Because he wants to disable the keyup event altogether? That's how I read it.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just break out of the handler if the value is empty?

```
$(element).keyup(function(e) {
    if (this.value.trim() == '')
        return;

    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: The keyup event will still occur unless he stops propagation.

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't matter if you skip the handler he doesn't want fired, right?

Comment: Returning from that particular handler isn't going to stop any others from firing.

Comment: True.  I'm making assumptions from the question.  Does he really need the event to stop, or the handlers not to execute... that's the question.  I started to write an answer with a proxy handler, but it started to seem unnecessary very quickly.